# Saving Extension Config Data Magento

Tags: magento

I've been trying to figure out exactly how does magento save the config data for a module given in  System.xml. reason?I would like to edit the data provided by the user before storing it in the database.
Any clues????

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a look at `Mage_Core_Model_Store::setConfig` function (and getConfig for reading the value). You will probbably have to write an observer that will listen to `store_save_before` event.

Magento stores configuration data in `core_config_data` database table - path column is the hierarhical structure of XML elements in system.xml file and is the same as XPath used for reading the default value out of config.xml file and value column contains the value that was saved.

When accessing the data with for e.g. `Mage::getStoreConfig( 'path', $storeId );` Magento first searches the table for path-value pair and if it doesn't find it it reads the default value from config.xml file.